# Access 2010 set variable to single field of a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I feel like this should be easy, but I haven't been able to come up with a clear answer for this after searching off and on all day.

I have a users table that has email addresses in it.

I have a combo box that references this table.

All I want to do, is set the email address field of the selected user to a string, so I can then do things with that.

just trying to get a string back from a sql query like :

```
"SELECT emailAddress FROM tblUsers WHERE id = " & Me.cmbUser.Value & ""
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Combo Box to return email address after user select user from list.

Assume your user tblUsershas User and Email fields

Set your combo box property:

1.Row  Source = SELECT User, Email FROM tblusers

2.Column Count = 2

3.Bound Column = 0 (0 is the first column and 1 is the second column which is email)

4.Column width = x";0" (x is your combox box width)

You can get email address from me.combobox.column(1).  Both me.combobox.value and me.comboxbox.column(0) is selected User

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't tried that. It totally works, but I was really just using the combo box for testing. I still would love to know how run a query against a table and get a string back out.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to execute the query, you have multiple options:

1. You can use [`DLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834404.aspx):

   **TL;DR:**
   `DLookup("Column", "Table", "Col=Value")` will execute `SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE Col=Value` and return the first row.

   For the query from your question, you need to use `DLookup` like this:

   ```
   Dim mail As String
   mail = Nz(DLookup("emailAddress", "tblUsers", "id = " & Me.cmbUser.Value))
   ```
2. You can load your SQL query with a `Recordset`.
   This makes more sense than `DLookup` if you need more user data from the table than just the email adress.

   ```
   Dim mail As String
   Dim phone As String

   Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
   Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT emailAddress, phoneNumber FROM tblUsers WHERE id = " & Me.cmbUser.Value)
   If Not RS.EOF Then
       mail = Nz(RS("emailAddress"))
       phone = Nz(RS("phoneNumber"))
   End If
   RS.Close
   Set RS = Nothing
   ```

   *(in order for this to work, your Access database needs a reference to any version of the `Microsoft DAO Object Library`...this should already be the case in most newer Access versions)*

Note the usage of [`Nz`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195223.aspx) in both examples - this is necessary if the mail adress can be `NULL`. Without `Nz`, the code would crash because of setting a string variable to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I actually found DLookup on my own earlier today and have been using it for what I needed. I will try your SQL example tomorrow as soon as I get a chance. you are my hero. ;op